issue with ingress https & a dummy domain
I deployed my nodejs-mongodb app using kubernetes. I have deployments for nodejs app and mongodb and two services to access them.
$ kubectl get deploy
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
mongodb   1/1     1            1           20h
backend   1/1     1            1           20h
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.43.0.1       <none>        443/TCP     6d2h
mongodb      ClusterIP   10.43.117.125   <none>        27017/TCP   20h
backend      ClusterIP   10.43.173.33    <none>        3000/TCP    20h

I have also an ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: deepscan-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "$remote_addr, $server_addr";
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 3000
            path: /

and here is its status:
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME               CLASS   HOSTS   ADDRESS      PORTS   AGE
myapp-ingress   nginx   *       server_private_IP   80      5d19h

I can access the app in browser using server's public_ip with http, i.e. http://public_ip. But it doesn't work with https.
to resolve this issue, I created a self-signed cert and key and created a secret and modified my ingress to
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: deepscan-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For "$remote_addr, $server_addr";
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: some_test_domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend
                port:
                  number: 3000
            path: /
  # This section is only required if TLS is to be enabled for the Ingress
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - some_test_domain.com
      secretName: my-tls-secret

and here is the status:
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME               CLASS   HOSTS         ADDRESS      PORTS     AGE
deepscan-ingress   nginx   some_test_domain.com   private_ip   80, 443   16m

I don't own any domain but I added this line in my /etc/hosts
the_private_ip    some_test_domain.com

I'm able to access app on the server using curl -k https://some_test_domain.com but I no longer can access my app using http(s)://public_ip from browser!
Does anyone have any idea how I can access my app using https via the public ip.
best

Have you gone through this documentation. It seems that you are not using 443 port which is in general used for https. Also can share any reference docs you are following
